# Count frequency of words under given index in a file

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to count occurrence of words under specific index in my file and print it out as a dictionary.

```
def count_by_fruit(file_name="file_with_fruit_data.txt"):
    with open(file_name, "r") as file:
        content_of_file = file.readlines()
        dict_of_fruit_count = {}
        for line in content_of_file:
            line = line[0:-1]
            line = line.split("\t")
            for fruit in line:
                fruit = line[1]
                dict_of_fruit_count[fruit] = dict_of_fruit_count.get(fruit, 0) + 1
    return dict_of_fruit_count


print(count_by_fruit())
```

Output: {'apple': 6, 'banana': 6, 'orange': 3}

I am getting this output, however, it doesn't count frequency of the words correctly. After searching around I didn't seem to find the proper solution. Could anyone help me to identify my mistake?

My file has the following content: (data separated with tabs, put "\t" in example as format is being altered by stackoverflow)

1. I am line one with \t apple \t from 2018
2. I am line two with \t orange \t from 2017
3. I am line three with \t apple \t from 2016
4. I am line four with \t banana \t from 2010
5. I am line five with \t banana \t from 1999

Comment: this guy is your friend, check it out https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer! You are right, this could be my potential friend, nevertheless, I am looking for an answer that can point out why my logic is incorrect and what causes it to print out abnormal values, so, I could figure out the right solution

Comment: well, if what you want is to find the mistake you need to follow the guidelines to produce a [Minimal,Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcvev)

Comment: I couldn't follow your link as the page doesn't exists but following the keywords I edited my question with minimal (hopefully), complete and verifiable example and an example of a file I am trying to iterate through :)

Comment: Can you please clarify where the tabs are exactly in each line?

Comment: the correct link is https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  :)

Comment: @myrtlecat clarified in the original message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping too many times over the same line. Notice that the results you are getting are all 3 times what you are expecting.

Also, in Python, you also do not need to read the entire file. Just iterate over the file object line by line.

Try:

```
def count_by_fruit(file_name="file_with_fruit_data.txt"):
    with open(file_name, "r") as f_in:
        dict_of_fruit_count = {}
        for line in f_in:
            fruit=line.split("\t")[1]
            dict_of_fruit_count[fruit] = dict_of_fruit_count.get(fruit, 0) + 1
    return dict_of_fruit_count
```

Which can be further simplified to:

```
def count_by_fruit(file_name="file_with_fruit_data.txt"):
    with open(file_name) as f_in:
        dict_of_fruit_count = {}
        for fruit in (line.split('\t')[1] for line in f_in):
            dict_of_fruit_count[fruit] = dict_of_fruit_count.get(fruit, 0) + 1
        return dict_of_fruit_count
```

Or, if you can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter 

def count_by_fruit(file_name="file_with_fruit_data.txt"):
    with open(file_name) as f_in:
        return dict(Counter(line.split('\t')[1] for line in f_in))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works indeed and I finally understood what was wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `for fruit in line:`.  Splitting the lines on the tabs is going to split them into three parts.  If you loop over those three parts every time, adding one to the count for each, then your counts are going to be 3 times as large as the actual data.

Below is how I would write this function, using generator expressions and `Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter

def count_by_fruit(file_name="file_with_fruit_data.txt"):
    with open(file_name, "r") as file:
        lines = (line[:-1] for line in file)
        fruit = (line.split('\t')[1] for line in lines)
        return Counter(fruit)
```

Comment: I've been trying to avoid Counter because I believed it is not really necessary in my case and can be done by other means. Your example works perfectly as well! Thank you for your detailed explanation, made my understanding more clear!